# Replacing a setTimeout() in an Angular Reactive Form with an Observable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I want to replace a setTimout() with an Observable in an Angular reactive form.

I have a grandchild component that serves a section of a larger reactive form, receives an array of data objects from an API endpoint, packs that data into a Form Array, and submits it to the form.  This works well.

The problem is that the asynchronous nature of our API endpoints causes the form data of this grandchild component to render old data before the new data can initialize itself and clear out the old data and repopulate the new data.  We've solved this with a setTimout() of 500 ms.  It works well on the front end.

The problem is that the setTimeout() is causing issues with our e2e testing failing because it completes the test before the data is loaded. Plus, a timeout is not a long term solution to this async issue... especially if the data could occasionally take longer than 1/2 second (not a usual case, but definitely plausible).

I'm hoping to replace my timeout with an observable as a better solution that won't block our tests and can handle async much more safely.  Problem is that I cannot get the observable to work and I'm still an RxJS novice.

Here is the original function with the timeout that is currently running:

```
setTimeout(() => {
      this.dataRow = [];
      for (let item of this.data.row) {
        this.dataRow.push(item);
      }
    }, 500);
```

Here is my attempt to recreate with an Observable:

```
this.dataRow = [];
   this.dataEmitter = from(this.data.row).pipe(delay(1000)).subscribe(data => this.dataRow.push(data);)
```

My code creates a data stream, but doesn't seem to work the same as the timeout.  How can I accomplish this?  Is this even the correct way to approach this problem?

Comment: You have this line in your code `this.dataRow.push(row);`. Are you sure you want to push `row` instead of `item` ?

Comment: @AsimHashmi.  You're correct.  I made that mistake when typing my example, but it's correct in my code base.  Thank you for the catch... edit made.

Comment: `of` not `from`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT:

```
this.dataEmitter = of(this.data.row).pipe(delay(1000)).subscribe(row => {
  for (let item of row) {
    this.dataRow.push(item);
  }
}
```

---

`delay(1000)` delays by 1 sec. for every emit. And your snippet is not correct - you can't `push(row)` because `row` is `undefined` (as seen in the snippet).

so if `this.data.row` is an Object, you need to make it iterable (like an array) if you want to emit `this.data.row` in "peaces".

But if you just want to get rid of `setTimeout`:

```
this.dataEmitter = from([this.data.row]).pipe(delay(1000)).subscribe(row => {
  for (let item of row) {
    this.dataRow.push(item);
  }
}
```

Comment: You're correct about my snippet, I transposed my code incorrectly for my example and have edited my question.  Thanks for catching that.

Comment: My observable is iterating correctly over the data.  I'm looking for an array of 'row' objects, and am receiving that correctly.  ``` ROW IN OBSERVABLE: Array(11) [ {...}, {...}, {...}, {...}, {...}, {...}, {...}, {...}, {...}, {...}, {...} ]```

Comment: Ok, if you just need to get rid of setTimeout - I edited

Answer (score 0):

Your code would be like this:

```
this.dataRow = []

of(this.data.row)
 .pipe(delay(500))
 .subscribe(data => {
   for(let item of data) {
     this.dataRow.push(item);
   }
 })
```

Comment: According to the RxJS docs, zip has been depricated? https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/zip

Comment: This will fire every 500 milliseconds, I think OP only wants an initial delay, not a running continually.

Comment: @AdrianBrand I updated code and changed `from` to `of` which will emit the whole array instead of emitting each value